# Can't run cells in Polynote - any ideas?

Tags: ubuntu, polynote

The installation (on ubuntu) seemed to go well, but when I try to run a cell (python or scala) I get:

```
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object 
in compiler mirror not found.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Java 8 worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

choose java 8 and restart polynotes